# Show sizes on productlist for configurable products

Tags: magento-2.1

I have a bunch of configurable products where I want to show the sizes available under the product price on the product list.

Every configurable product has simple products attached each with a size attribute like XL, L, M, S.

How do I do that in my template file: `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml` ?

Comment: It is showing by default in Magento-2.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from admin panel. Go to

> Store > Atrributes > Product > your_attribute > Storefront Properties

set `Used in Product Listing` to **Yes**